# Changing Apple's individual developer account to Organizational

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I have Apple's individual developer account which i want to convert into Organizational account . **I wanna ask that is this going to effect my Apps that are already on App Store in any way ??** I have searched about it but didn't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: No this change no disturb your apps: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/ If you read "Can I enroll as an individual and have my company appear as the seller on the App Store?" only for name company :). A year ago we make the same change in a company and works perfectly

Comment: @JosePoseS Thanks mate :D .... Put this comment in answer i'll accept it and upvote it

Comment: @OsamainBashir  Thanks for vote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this change no disturb your apps: [Development Apple](http://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships) If you read "Can I enroll as an individual and have my company appear as the seller on the App Store?" only for name company :). A year ago we make the same change in a company and works perfectly